# In this case, how can I write the queue.put

Tags: python, multithreading, dns, queue

I'm writing a program to get the domain in same server and it also can scan the web directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#encoding = utf-8
import threading
import urllib,urllib2,httplib
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError

import Queue,sys
import re
concurrent = 5
url = sys.argv[1]

class Scanner(threading.Thread):


    def __init__(self, work_q):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.work_q = work_q


    def getdomains(self):
        doreq = Request('http://www.logontube.com/website/'+ url)
        response = urlopen(doreq)
        html = response.read()
        response.close()
        domains = re.findall('<br><a href=\"(.*?)\" target=\"_blank\"',html)
        return domains

    def run(self):
        alldomains = self.getdomains()
        pathline = [line.rstrip() for line in open("path.txt")]


        while True:
            for aim in alldomains:
                for path in pathline:
                    path = self.work_q.get()

                    req = Request(aim+path)
                    try:
                        response = urlopen(req)
                    except URLError, e:
                        if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
                            print aim+path,'Not Found'
                        elif hasattr(e,'code'):
                            print aim+path,'Not Found'
                    else:
                        try:
                            logs = open('log.txt',"a+")
                        except(IOError):
                            print "[x] Failed to create log file"
                        print aim+path,"Found"
                        logs.writelines(aim+path+"\n")
                        logs.close()

def main():


    work_q = Queue.Queue()
    paths = [line.rstrip() for line in open("path.txt")]
    for i in range(concurrent):
        t = Scanner(work_q)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

    for path in paths:
        work_q.put(path)

    work_q.join()


main()
```

The problem is this program only do the loop of the path, so i only can get the scan result of one website.
I've found the problem,

```
for path in paths:
        work_q.put(path) # The program finishes when it puts all the path
```

If you want to help me to test this program, you may need some directory of website(save it as path.txt)

```
/default.asp
/index.asp
/index.htm
/index.html
/index.jsp
/index.php
/admin.asp
/admin.php
/admin.shtml
/admin.txt
/admin_admin.asp
/config.asp
/inc/
/login.asp
/login.jsp
/login.php
/login/
/phpinfo.php
/readme.txt
/robots.txt
/test.asp
/test.html
/test.txt
/test.php
/news/readme.txt
/addmember/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a:

```
while 1:
   pass
```

or something that waits until your threads are completed then it exits.

What is happening is that you are starting the threads but you are terminating the main thread so you never get to see the results of your threads.

Comment: I can see the result, but it is not complete.  the program don't do loop of  "for aim in alldomains", i've only got the result of first aim.

Comment: Well what is the value of alldomains do `print alldomains` How many domains are in there ?

Comment: the quantity of the alldomains depende on url = sys.argv[1], it is the quantity of the website in the same server.

Comment: for example, you can run it, python webscanner.py www.facebook.com